# Multiple exceptions

Tags: java, exception

When I execute this code I get `caughtjava.lang.CloneNotSupportedException` as an output! Why doesn't the `NullPointerException` get caught?

```
package arrays;

public class NestedTry {
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        try{
            try{
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
            finally{
                throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("caught"+e.toString());
            //which excpetion will be printed here?? :P
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply beacuse `finally` block executes for sure.

```
try{
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    finally{
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
        }
```

In the above code first `NullPointerException()` gets thrown, but for this `try`, `finally` block is again throwing `CloneNotSupportedException();`

So ultimately

```
catch(Exception e)
 {
    System.out.println("caught"+e.toString());
    //which excpetion will be printed here?? :P
 }
```

The above `catch` instead of catching `NullPointerException` catches the `finally` block's `CloneNotSupportedException` and prints `caughtjava.lang.CloneNotSupportedException`.